# Use MonoDroid generated resources in java files?

Tags: resources, xamarin.android

I created a MonoDroid Library Project and added some resources to the project. When I use these resources in a C# class it works fine. (for this I had to add the  and  tags to the .csproj file, copied from an application project).

Now I want to use the resources I added in a .java file. I added the Java source file and set the build action to AndroidJavaSource. Unfortunately I can't find the resources using the R namespace. There is no generated .java file that contains my resources. Is there a way to use MonoDroid generated resources in my java file?

Background: I want to use ActionBar in my projects and thought about using Android's ActionBarCompat project (located in [...]\android-sdk\samples\android-14\ActionBarCompat), as source files, in a Library project. The .java files in there use layout and other resources from its res folder, which I would copy over, too. I want to use the stated approach above. If it's (currently) not possible, an answer with a better approach is welcome. (And no, please don't point me to other ActionBar implementations, thank you. That's not the scope of the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this problem was solved by Xamarin some time ago. I'm using an older version of MonoDroid and didn't have the time to upgrade to a newer version. Here's a workaround.

The Xamarin.Android compiler links in resources from library files and creates a function called UpdateIdValues() in the Resources.designer.cs file of the app project. The function is used to fix the resource ids from the library project to the correct ids eventually generated in the main project. For this reason the resource ids in library projects are declared "public static int" instead of "public const int" as in the app project.

At some point they forgot to actually call this function somewhere. So a Xamarin developer offered a workaround:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/5816/#Comment_5816

The workaround works for me, and when I upgrade Xamarin.Studio, I can remove the workaround again, since it should then work out of the box.